# Parse XML using a XSD in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have a XML file and a a bunch of XSD files with schemas. How do I parse the XML file using the correct XSD file and schema in PHP?

Comment: There is also this library, with examples https://github.com/goetas/xsd2php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [XmlReader](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) extensions

- [`DOMDocument::schemaValidate`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php)  —  Validates a document based on a schema
- [`XMLReader::setSchema`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.setschema.php) — Validate document against XSD

to validate documents against a schema.

Answer (score 2):

Check this tool - http://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP. It sounds exactly what you're asking.
You can marshal/unmarshal XML usind generated from XSD PHP classes.

Comment: Good idea but how do I drive this thing? ;) No use cases or examples.

Comment: Yes the problem is this library is lack of documentation